# Finding value of instance variable in JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

The following code shows the structure of my method which is located in the 'Test' class and I need to access the value of my Boolean variable 'test_var'.

```
public Decision declare(){
 class Decide extends Decision{
       public boolean test_var = false;

 }

 final Decide  d = new Decide();

 d.Add(new Rule("decision")){
  public void take(){
    d.test_var = true;
    }

  });
  return d;
}
```

I tried the following in JNI but the android application crashes when trying to find the boolean value through the GetObjectField.

```
    jclass decision_class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Test$1Decision");

jfieldID varID = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, decision_class, "test_var", "Z");

if(NULL == varID) log("varID not found\n")

else log("varID was found!!!\n")

//jboolean result = (*env)->GetBooleanField(env, obj, varID);
jboolean result = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, obj, varID);

log("In C the boolean value is:", result)
```

Am I accessing the field in the wrong way? Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"Test$1Decision"` <-- looks like you haven't specified the package name. You should check the return values from all the JNI functions. For example, `FindClass` will return `NULL` if the class can't be found.

Comment: FindClass is not returning null and the fieldID is being retrieved. The problem is in the GetObjectField part

Comment: Well, why are you using `GetObjectField` rather than `GetBooleanField`?

Comment: I tried with GetBooleanField but it still crashes

Comment: Crashes how? What exactly does the stack trace look like?

Comment: Please post the correct code using GetBooleanField() and the crash.

Comment: The java code you posted is wrong, it doesn't have any help.

Comment: If you call the right method (GetBooleanField as others have pointed out) and you're sure you have the correct field id it must be the obj that's the problem. Where do you get that from?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at my code

```
cjv.f_id      = (*cjv.env)->GetStaticFieldID(cjv.env, cjv.clazz, "UiMenu", "Z");
cjv.f_boolean = (*cjv.env)->GetStaticBooleanField(cjv.env, cjv.clazz, cjv.f_id);
```

In my case I need it to be static but you should get an idea instead of obj you should try with boolean field.